# Nodejs Convert Incoming Stream Windows 1252 auf UTF-8

Tags: node.js, encoding, utf-8

I create nodesjs `net` server, the sender sends the data in `Windows 1252`.

### Question:

How can I convert the data from `Windows 1252` to `utf-8` which is required in the rest of my application?

According to:
https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_setencoding_encoding

*Call this function to cause the stream to return strings of the specified encoding instead of Buffer objects.*

`client.setEncoding 'utf8'` should return a string in `utf-8` format, but I still get `questionmarks` in my strings instead of e.g. `ä,ö,ü`

### Code

```
exports.createServer = (io) ->
  server = net.createServer(
    {
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      pauseOnConnect: false
    },
    (socket)->
      createClient(socket, io)
  )

  server.listen portHl7

  server.on('error', (err) ->
    if (err.code == 'EADDRINUSE')
      console.log 'Address in use, retrying...'
      setTimeout(
        () ->
          server.close()
          self.createServer()
        1000
      )
  )

  server.on('close', (err) ->
    console.log "server closed"
  )

createClient = (socket, io) ->
  client = socket

  client.name = client.remoteAddress + ":" + client.remotePort
  clients.push(client)
  console.log "Client #{client.name} connected"

  client.setEncoding 'utf8'

  client.addListener 'data', (data) ->
    parser = new Parser()
    s = new stream.Readable()
    ...
```

Additional information:

- Possible encoding formats: https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer